# How to apply back pressure with Combine buffer operator to avoid flatMap to ask an infinite demand upstream?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

I'm trying to use Combine to do several millions concurrent request through the network. Here is a mock up of the naive approach I'n using:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

let cancellable = (0..<1_000_000).publisher
  .map(some_preprocessing)
  .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(32)) { request in
    URLSession.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
      .map(\.data)
      .catch { _ in
        return Just(Data())
      }
  }
  .sink { completion in
    print(completion)
  } receiveValue: { value in
    print(value)
  }

// Required in a command line tool
sleep(100)
```

This pipeline first creates a request, the the request is done in `flatMap` to confine errors. Also, `flatMap` merges several requests to they are effectively done concurrently, which is great.

The issue is that it will literally make 1,000,000 requests concurrently, so I added the parameter `maxPublishers` which limits the number of publishers that are subscribed at the same time in `flatMap`. This kind of work, only 32 publishers are active at the same time, but unfortunately `some_preprocessing` will still be performed 1,000,000 times before `flatMap` will be executed.

I expected `flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(32))` to apply some back pressure, i.e. only requesting items from the upstream publisher `map` when `maxPublishers` < 32. This does not seem to be the case, and it fills up the RAM rapidly and delays the processing.

I then tried to use the `buffer` operator that is used to introduce back pressure between a producer and a consumer, but Apple documentation is so poor I don't understand its functioning (more specifically the `prefechStrategy` argument).

So I tried different combinations such as:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

let cancellable = (0..<1_000_000).publisher
  .map(some_preprocessing)
  .buffer(size: 32, prefetch: .byRequest, whenFull: .dropNewest)
  .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(32)) { request in
    URLSession.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
      .map(\.data)
      .catch { _ in
        return Just(Data())
      }
  }
  .sink { completion in
    print(completion)
  } receiveValue: { value in
    print(value)
  }

// Required in a command line tool
sleep(100)
```

This does not seem to do anything useful though, `flatMap` still requests as much element as it can.

**How to properly apply back pressure in this case? I.e I need the upstream `map` publisher to "wait" for demand asked by the downstream publisher `flatMap`, which should only ask items when it as an empty slot.**

Comment: Take a look at my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66982854/how-to-limit-flatmap-concurrency-in-combine-still-having-all-source-events-proce. Note that your use of a sequence publisher plus map is flawed because, as you have rightly observed, it fails to communicate the backpressure; basically sequence is sort of a toy in this regard. But if you use a more realistic publisher you'll get better results (I think). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61143246/why-does-publishers-map-consume-upstream-values-eagerly for a workaround

Comment: Thank you this solves my issue! This `map` thing really looks like a bug to me.

Comment: You solved it? How cool is that? :) Even though you're pulling the information from existing answers, I think it would be best for you to provide an actual answer to your own question, as that would probably be most helpful to future readers.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention: if you're trying to understand `buffer` you might find my explanation useful: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTimers/operatorsbuffer.html

Comment: You are right, I'm gonna put the answer there also! This solved the infinite demand issue, though I have another memory issue not related to Combine now (catched errors appear to leak NSURL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be a Combine bug, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61143246/why-does-publishers-map-consume-upstream-values-eagerly). Using `Publishers.Sequence` causes the following operator to accumulate every value sent downstream before proceeding.

A workaround is to type-erase the sequence publisher:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

let cancellable = (0..<1_000_000).publisher
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()  // <----
  .map(some_preprocessing)
  .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(32)) { request in
    URLSession.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
      .map(\.data)
      .catch { _ in
        return Just(Data())
      }
  }
  .sink { completion in
    print(completion)
  } receiveValue: { value in
    print(value)
  }

// Required in a command line tool without running loop
sleep(.max)
```

Comment: `flatMap()` requests an infinite demand upon subscription. And the upstream may satisfy it instantly. So the issue lies in the `flatMap()`. Unfortunately Combine lacks lazy operator, but we can implement it ourselves.